# Not able to login from chrome in moodle 3.1

Tags: moodle

I am using LAD authorization method for access the system but I have admin user which is in moodle database, all Lad users are able to login in the system from chrome, but the user from database not able to login from the chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place the manual & email authentication priority order above the priority of the LAD authorization method?
That way, it will attempt it with those methods before resorting to the LAD method.

If for example, the admin user is also present in another method, it might cause a failure instead of being recognised, depending on the programming of the auth plugin.